# SilverLight UploadFile Controller

Tags: .net, silverlight, file-upload

I"m working on a .net framework 4.0 website (written in c#) What i"m trying to do is to upload big files from the client side (user) local system to my webhost.

I"m looking for a good free silverlight controller (in order to be able to split the file). 
I"ve allready found a couple of controllers but i didn't know how to embade it to my website.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the best controller to do what you want to do.

http://silverlightfileupld.codeplex.com/

To embed the controller into your application you have to include all the ".dll" files from the tool as references.

Was that clear enough?

**EDIT:**

You can use the WebClient class.

```
 WebClient client = new WebClient();
 client.UploadStringAsync(uri, data)
```

Also check out this link:
http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/660968/how-can-Upload-the-xml-data-in-specific-url-in-sil

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much

It's a great control, but how do i configure my upload address.

In this control tho only thing i can configure is the 'upload page' attribute, but i want to upload the file to a specfic libary (not a file) with a url address.